# NoClassDefFoundError error when testing xerial SQLite JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite, noclassdeffounderror

I am unable to run the SQLite [sample](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) and it's maddening. I get a complex, multi-line error message including:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  Sample/jar

...

Could not find the main class: Sample.jar.
```

I suspect a classpath error might be involved, so here is my classpath (Win7):

.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\;E:\Dropbox\Personal\Development\BlueJ examples;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\sqlite-jdb-3.7.2.jar

I am running the command prompt inside the E:...BlueJ examples folder (FWIW a normal `"java -jar hello.jar"` command prompt runs just fine from within this folder). Can somebody pls help figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath needs to include a reference to the jar file itself, not just the directory it is in.

Comment: The classpath you've entered here is different to the one you've entered above! Which one are you using? Can you edit your question and give details of the full command line you are trying to run. And just to check the obvious, have you got the class called Sample.java in the directory you are running in?

Comment: @DaveRiz Yes the second classpath is updated (I have edited the OP) to include the link to the jarfile as suggested.

Comment: Trial end error worked! Posting here in hope I can save another noob the frustration (and embarrassment):
1. The command line in the tutorial has a semicolon for Win and a colon for Mac/Linux
2. Compile the .java file into .class
> javac Sample.java 
4. Run Sample.class using java in its own directory:
> java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-VERSION.jar" Sample

I am still confused about the observation that the sqlite-jdbc-VERSION.jar has to be in the same folder as the .class file being run. Why can't java find it based on its CLASSPATH information?

Comment: Why is it that if I remove Sqlite-jdbc-VERSION.jar from the local folder with the Sample.java and Sample.class files, the command line will not run?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, had to start another answer as this one is quite longwinded.

Glad things are working but I think you probably misunderstood what I was trying to say in my previous answer.

The classpath is a series of places that java will look for your classes. If the classpath element is a folder then all .class files in there will be included in the search. Jar files are essentially compressed folders, so you have to include the name of the jar file on the classpath. You can put the actual jar file in any directory you like so long as it is referenced on the classpath (using the full path to the file). In your comment to my other answer you have added the sqlite-jdbc.jar to the classpath file but since you have not reference it with a full file path java will only look in the current directory when you run.

Hope that makes sense - and thanks for the acceptance :)